# Python + Selenium Web scraping dynamic elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to extract the following information from an SEC archives website.

1)Large accelerated filer
2)Accelerated filer
3)Non-accelerated filer
4)Smaller reporting company
5)Emerging growth company

This is how it appears on the site:

```
Large accelerated filer     ☒       
Accelerated filer           ☐
Non-accelerated filer       ☐  (Do not check if a smaller reporting company)         
Smaller reporting company   ☐
Emerging growth company     ☐
```

In some cases, one or more of the items may not be present. I want to write a generic code that can extract these values for a number of companies. Now the problem I'm facing is that the structure of HTML is changing from company to company. So far I've come across 3 different structures (Please see below for HTML structure). How do I get write the code to generalize across different structures?

```
<td valign="bottom">Large&nbsp;accelerated&nbsp;filer</td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom">☒</td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom">Accelerated&nbsp;filer</td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom">☐</td></tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<td valign="bottom"><font style="white-space:nowrap">Non-accelerated&nbsp;filer</font></td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom">☐&nbsp;&nbsp;(Do not check if a smaller reporting company)</td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom">Smaller&nbsp;reporting&nbsp;company</td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom">☐</td></tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<td valign="bottom">Emerging&nbsp;growth&nbsp;company</td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom">☐</td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom"></td>
<td valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom"></td></tr>
```

Another structure:

```
filer&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="FONT-FAMILY:WINGDINGS">x</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Accelerated filer&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="FONT-FAMILY:WINGDINGS">¨</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Non-accelerated filer&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="FONT-FAMILY:WINGDINGS">¨</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Smaller reporting company&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="FONT-FAMILY:WINGDINGS">¨</font> </font>
```

Another one :

```
<tbody><tr>
<td width="63%"></td>
<td valign="bottom" width="2%"></td>
<td width="35%"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"> <p style="text-indent:2.00em"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">Large accelerated filer&nbsp;&nbsp;<font face="WINGDINGS">¨</font></font></p></td>
<td valign="bottom"><font size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="bottom"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">Accelerated filer&nbsp;&nbsp;<font face="WINGDINGS">þ</font></font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"> <p style="text-indent:2.00em"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">Non-accelerated filer&nbsp;&nbsp;<font face="WINGDINGS">¨</font>&nbsp;&nbsp; (Do not check if a smaller reporting company)</font></p></td>
<td valign="bottom"><font size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="bottom"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">Smaller reporting Company&nbsp;&nbsp;<font face="WINGDINGS">¨</font></font></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I have edited your question a bit, let me know if the change looks good

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/60596808/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this combination (| operator) of 3 XPaths to get what you need (items which have been ticked) :

```
//td[.="☒"]/preceding::td[string-length(.)>1][1]/text()|//font[.="x"]/following::text()[1]|//font[.="þ"]/preceding::text()[1]
```

The html you provide isn't well formed. If it doesn't work, please provide something else.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it using combination (not exactly what you provided, but with a little tweak)